# SKConstraint not updating node's position

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm using an SKConstraint to keep a node a certain distance from a specific point:

```
let range = SKRange(lowerLimit: 0, upperLimit: 200)
let constraint = SKConstraint.distance(range, toPoint: self.fixedPoint)
self.node.constraints = [self.constraint]
```

The constraint keeps the node within the specified range just fine, but if I try to find the difference between the node's position and that specific point, the value can go above the `upperLimit`.

```
let diffX = self.node.position.x - self.fixedPoint.x //this can go above the upperLimit
```

Does the SKConstraint only restrain the node's position visually? That doesn't make sense to me. Has anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: The documentation says "...if [the node] lies outside the specified range, the node is _pushed_ or _pulled_ along this line until it lies within the range." It sounds like a distance constraint is more like a rubber band than a rope.

Comment: Interesting. It seems to me that if the constraint is keeping the node at the right position, the node's position property should match that though...

Comment: How far outside of the range is the position of the node?

Comment: I can drag the node so it can be hundreds of units (points?) away from the upperLimit.

Comment: sounds like you are checking it before constraints are applied,  check diffX in the didApplyConstraints method

Comment: That was it, thank you both for the help!

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I'm currently following the delegation pattern to integrate a joystick instance with my GameScene (where the joystick instance produces a velocity vector in its `touchesMoved()` to apply to a `SKSpriteNode` in the `GameScene`). Is there a proper way to reference functions like `didApplyConstraints` from the delegate (the GameScene) inside the delegating instance? The docs suggest that I shouldn't call `didApplyConstraints` directly, as it is called once per frame. However, I'd like to calculate this vector from the joystick _after_ it has been constrained to the joystick base.

Comment: Calling it directly means scene.didApplyConstraints(). Just override the function like you do with didBeginContact